# Keycloak для большого количества авторизаций

Tags: авторизация, проектирование, регистрация, keycloak

Я проектирую приложение которое подразумевает большое количество авторизаций, регистраций и активных сессий пользователей. Как считаете можно ли для этого функционала использовать keycloak? Какие проблемы могут возникнуть?
Я встречал использование keycloack только для внутренних целей с админками